# How to match entire cell content when using Cells.Replace() on a WorkSheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to replace every cell in my worksheet that contains just zero with blank.

This code will replace all zeros with blank but it will find all zeros i.e. 12045 will become 1245. I need some parameter that will match the entire cell content to see if the cell only contains a single zero.

```
ws.Cells.Replace(0, "");
```

Comment: Are you using `Interop` library for excel operations? Can you show us more code to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes I use Interop. What exactly do you have in mind? ws is sucessfully defined worksheet and the code above works. I just need some way for it to match the entire cell content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace whole word, then pass additional parameter to  [`Cells.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.replace?view=excel-pia#definition) i.e [`XlLookAt.xlWhole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xllookat?view=excel-pia#definition)

```
 ws.Cells.Replace(0, "", XlLookAt.xlWhole);
                       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This needs to be added.
```

---

[XlLookAt Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xllookat?view=excel-pia#definition):

> Specifies whether a match is made against the whole of the search text
> or any part of the search text.